# Read from textfile and split each line into different strings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text-files

i have to read from a textfile which contains the following formatting

```
PRODUCTID PRODUCTNAME CUSTOMERID CUSTOMERNAME AMOUNT.
```

The textfile contains 11 line and for each one of them i must store each eg. productid into one string, and productname into one string.

I have tried like this which only stores the length of each line..

```
   List<string> list = new List<string>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"Budget.txt"))
        {

            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {               
                list.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Created a class which hold the data

Comment: Did you mean you have a delimited table in the text file

Comment: You might also want to add a **clear** example of the text file contents, since it matters.

Comment: Can the `productname` and `customername` have spaces ? With a *clear* example i mean ... to have actual data.

Comment: Yeah it can have spaces, didnt think about that!

Comment: May or may you not change the file contents yourself and add e.g. a `|` between records on the same line ?

Comment: I fixed it! But of course now i have more problems.. I forgot to add Date to the class which i import to but it wont recognize the string as a valid DateTime.

Comment: datum = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(field[4],
                                                                                "yyyyMMdd", 
                                                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                                                                DateTimeStyles.None)),

Comment: The string input is 20170102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that rapresent your file line, like this:

```
public class Procuct {
    public string ProductId {get;set;}
    public string ProductName {get;set;}
    public string CustomerId {get;set;}
    public string CustomerName {get;set;}
    public string Amount{get;set;}
}
```

Then create a list of product to store them:

```
    List<Procuct> list = new List<Procuct>();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"Budget.txt"))
    {

        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {               
            var temp = line.Split(" ");
            list.Add(new Product{
                ProductId = temp[0],
                ProductName = temp[1],
                CustomerId = temp[2],
                CustomerName = temp[3],
                Amount = temp[4]
            });
        }
    }
```

Once are stored you can use LINQ to get the information that you want.

Comment: It works, thanks alot! Just have one problem, i want to split it by "\t" but it says cannot convert from string to char

Comment: Ops sorry, try with '\t'

Comment: This is only correct if the productname and customername doesn't contain any spaces

Comment: @Jim he wrote the format line and I have supposed that is correct

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with TextFieldParser Class it is used to parse delimited text lignes as columns

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
using (TextFieldParser parser = new    TextFieldParser("C:\\csv.txt"))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { " " };
    while (true)
    {
    string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();
    if (parts == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} field(s)", parts.Length);
    }
}
}
}
```

There is a useful examples in this [Topic](https://www.dotnetperls.com/textfieldparser)

Answer (score -1):

You can use some code like below to get what you want

```
static void Main(String[] args) {

    var allRecords = new List<Record>();
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Budget.txt")) {
        allRecords.Add(new Record(line));
    }
}

public class Record {
    public string ProductId { get; private set; }
    public string ProductName { get; private set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }

    public Record(string line) {
        var items = line.Split();
        ProductId = items[0];
        ProductName = items[1];
        CustomerId = items[2];
        CustomerName = items[3];
        Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(items[4]);
    }

    public override String ToString() {
        return $"ProductId:{ProductId}, ProductName:{ProductName}, CustomerId:{CustomerId}, CustomerName:{CustomerName}, Amount:{Amount}";
    }

}
```

As your question is not very clear, I assume that your file format is as demonstrated by the example below

```
10 Enchiladas 27 John Doe 15.00 
11 HotDogs 27 John Doe 5.00 
12 Burgers 29 Jane Doe 10.00 
.
.
.
and so on
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems like this is what the OP is looking for